# Problem with ag grid after using livewire

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css, ag-grid, laravel-livewire

Edit: The table is rendered but it is so thin that you can't see anything, tailwind styles like h-full etc. don't help

After using livewire the table component stopped working, it generates pagination sections but does not render columns with data, data is available in both places. Pagination shows the number of addresses correctly.
There is code for x-table component and livewire component https://pastebin.com/n1dWjvK4
There is php code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Addresses;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Address;

class Index extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        $addresses = Address::where('is_active', 1)->get();
        // Trzeba zmienić render w controlerze ale nie generuje się tablica
        return view('livewire.addresses.index', [
            'addresses' => Address::where('is_active', 1)->get()
        ])->extends('layouts.main');
    }
}
```